# Enzyme simulate onClick event on a given position

Tags: onclick, textarea, enzyme

I am writing a test case to simulate the user clicking on a Textarea on a given caret position.

I tried to simulate 'click' event with a caret position using selectionStart and selectionEnd as:

```
it('onClick', () => {
  const event = { target: { selectionStart: 3, selectionEnd: 3 } };
  wrapper.find('textarea').simulate('click', event);
})
```

This does not work and i feel this is a incorrect way of setting the cursor position inside a element with the onCLick event.

Any suggestions on how to simulate a click event with cursor position for a textArea ..?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` in textarea's dom element:

```
it('onClick', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<MyComp></MyComp>) // <-- Note that shallow doesn't work
  const textareaWrapper = component3.find('textarea') // find textarea
  const textarea = textareaWrapper.getDOMNode() // get textarea's dom element
  textarea.selectionStart = 3 // set cursor position start
  textarea.selectionEnd = 3 // set cursor position end
  textareaWrapper.simulate('click') // simulate click
  ...
})
```

Ps: you should `mount` your element in order to access the dom elements.